# Mocking a higher order component with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I want to ensure that a HOC component is being called with jest, but I can't seem to get `jest.mock` to work. My HOC is like this:

```
const withEntity = (
  ...args
) => {
  const wrappedComponent = WrappedComponent => {
    const innerComponent = ({ ...props }) => {    
      return (
        <WrapperComponent
          {...props}
        >
          <WrappedComponent />
        </WrapperComponent>
      );
    };

    innerComponent.propTypes = {
      ...
    };

    return innerComponent;
  };

  wrappedComponent.propTypes = {
    ...
  };

  return wrappedComponent;
};

withEntity.propTypes = {
  ...
};

export default withEntity;
```

In a separate file, the `withEntity` function is called like this:

```
export const DoSomething = withEntity(...args)(MyComponent);
```

Then, in the testing file for the `DoSomething` component, i'm trying to import the `withEntity` function and mock it like so:

```
import withEntity from "../../../shared/entity/higher_order_components/withEntity";
jest.mock("../../../shared/entity/higher_order_components/withEntity");
```

But when I actually attempt to run the test, I get this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _withEntity.default)(...) is not a function
```

Not sure what to make of that error, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mocking your HOC should look like this:

```
jest.mock('../your/HOC', () => () => 
    Component => props => <Component {...props} /> 
)
```

it can be read as :

```
jest.mock('../your/HOC', () => `
```

create a mock that returns your HOC function,

```
() =>
```

the function that returns your HOC aka `withEntity(...args)`,

```
Component => props => <Component {...props} />
```

the HOC itself, which is a function that gets the component and return a function that get the props and return a function that returns the rendered component with its props.

Comment: What should those two `Component`s be? `jest.fn()` themselves?

Comment: What do you mean with 2 Components, the first one is the component coming in as an argument then return it as rendered component in the last function.

Comment: Also updated my answer to make it clear what happens there

Comment: I was able to get it to work with ```jest.mock("../../../shared/entity/higher_order_components/withEntity", () =>
  jest.fn(() => jest.fn(Component => props => <Component {...props} />))
);```. Now my (hopefully) last question is: how do I check if the internal mock function (i.e. `jest.fn(Component ...`) was also called? I've tried `expect(withEntity()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` but jest is saying it's been called 0 times.

Comment: Why do you want to test this. I mean it is obvious that it was called, otherwise your component would not have been rendered.

Comment: You're right, not worth testing that it was called but I think it is worth testing that it was called with a specific argument, which I failed to mention earlier. Do you think it makes sense to do that and if so, how might I approach it?

Comment: I ended up just shallow rendering and then looking for the component being passed instead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In my case because I am using typescript this is what works for me.

```js
jest.mock('components/MyComponent', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default({children}: any) {
    return children(() => {});
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is basically putting the below snippet into setupTests.js if you wish the render your component without the HOC affecting it.

```js
jest.mock('./pathTo/yourHOC', () => Component => {
  return Component
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  .mock(
    './pathTo/yourHOC',
    () => () => (Component) => {
      return Component;
    })
```