# Is it possible to wrap each individual test in a wrapper component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using material-UI components in my React components. Therefore I will need to apply the `<MuiThemeProvider></MuiThemeProvider>` component around all my components in my tests.

My components are located in individual folders:

```
./src/components/Header/Header.tsx
./src/components/Header/Header.test.ts
./src/components/Header/...
./src/components/Footer/Footer.tsx
./src/components/Footer/Footer.test.ts
./src/components/Footer/...
// etc.
```

A test would have to look like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Header from './Header';

it('matches snapshot', () => {
  const container = render(
    // This theme provider is necessary since my components depend on it.
    // But rather don't want to include this in all my components. 
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Header />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But now I'd have to define the MuiThemeProvider in each of my tests.

Is it possible to do this once for all my tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a higher order component with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198965/mocking-a-higher-order-component-with-jest)

Comment: Maybe I don't really follow that example. But I don't want to mock the HOC per-se. I just want to 'wrap' it around all of them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found it: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup

Turns out it's a react-testing-library thing.

You can modify the render function to wrap a component (provider) in the render method.

Simply change the import of the render function:

Create the function containing with the 'wrapper' component:

```
// test-utils.js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'my-ui-lib'
import { TranslationProvider } from 'my-i18n-lib'
import defaultStrings from 'i18n/en-x-default'

const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme="light"> // here it is
      <TranslationProvider messages={defaultStrings}>
        {children}
      </TranslationProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'

// override render method
export { customRender as render }
```

And then start using it like this:

```
// my-component.test.js
- import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
+ import { render, fireEvent } from '../test-utils';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. It avoids a lot of repetition when using the render() function in every single test block. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can mock your higher-order component using `jest.mock`.

It can something like following

```
jest.mock("hoc-module", () => {
    return {
        hocFunction: function(hocConf) {
            return function(component) {
                component.defaultProps = {
                    ...component.defaultProps,
                    mockPropKey: mockPropValue
                };
                return component;
            };
          }
    };
});
```

P.S: I wrote the above code on the fly.

Comment: How would this look like for the MuiThemeProvider? My component expects that a theme object is available, from which certain values are used.